# Read-Host list of filenames and then export the Input to a csv file

Tags: powershell, export-csv, read-host

I am trying to do a simply read host and export the user input to a csv file.

```
$List = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter List of files (exclude file extention)'|
Export-Csv "c:\user.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

All I get in my file is:

```
"length"
"42"
```

I think I need to declare a custom object but what I want is:

User inputs:

```
filename1
filename2
```

`export-csv C:\list.csv` should have:

```
filename1
filename2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your expected output looks a lot more like a text file rather than a csv.

Comment: How should a user enter different filenames? Delimited by what? (a comma, a semi-colon, spaces? What is your intended use? Should the entered filenames exist somewhere? What if a user enters an empty string or something like "blah blah blah". Is that OK with you?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned using a `PSCustomObject`, so why not use it?

```
$R_Input = Read-Host -Prompt "Exclude extension! `nEnter File Name" 
$R_Input = $R_Input -split ","

    [PSCustomObject]@{

        "First File Name"  = $R_Input[0]
        "Second File Name" = $R_Input[1]

    } | Export-Csv -Path "c:\user.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append

<#Input

Exclude extension! 
Enter File Name: Path Number One, Path Number two

#>


<#OutPut

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Import-Csv c:\user.csv

First File Name Second File Name
--------------- ----------------
Name Number One  Name Number two

#>
```

**EDIT:**

If you dont care about the file names being in a same column, you can use a `for` loop to  iterate though all input (*seperated by a comma*), and passed into a `PSCustomObject`. Now it shouldn't matter how much names they input.

```
$R_Input = Read-Host -Prompt "Exclude extension! `nEnter File Name" 
$R_Input = $R_Input.Trim() -split ","

    for ($i=0; $i -lt $R_Input.Count; $i++) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{

            "File Name"  = $R_Input[$i]

        } | Export-Csv -Path "c:\user.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force -Append
    }
```

Comment: THe problem is, i'm not sure how many lines the user will input.

Comment: I'm getting the empty pipe element.

Comment: Also, pardon the typos. I'm on my phone lol

Comment: Can you elaborate on the error you're getting? What do you mean?

Comment: An empty pipe element is not allowed.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement

Comment: What did you type in? I'd remove the csv file first as well, or create a new one with a different name. It's will only export whatever you type in. Can you open a new instance of whatever ide you're using, or console, and copy & paste the code , then run it. It works just fine for me.

Comment: His code is fine, you're copy pasting it wrong. The only way I can imagine you're getting that error is if you do `| Export-Csv ....` without passing any object to it. @Harry123

Comment: @Santi, thx for the reconfirmation! Had me thinking I typed something wrong lol

Comment: Thanks, yeah i copied it wrong.  However, when I type in copy and paste a list of files like this:

file1
filetest
fileold
Filetest2

I get this inside the csv file:

#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"3"

Comment: @Harry123, you're not comma `(,)` sperating the file names.

Comment: So when it asks you for input: FileOne, File Two, File Three, etc. All sperated by a comma. This way it doesn't matter if there's a *space* in the file name.

Comment: dang, i think the user inputs it as a single column list.

Comment: If the file names don't have a space, you can split it by a space instead of a comma.

Comment: thanks.  the csv still shows:

#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"3"

Comment: I honestly have no clue what you're doing, you're just saying what it's outputting. How is it you're outputting? What are you inputting? A list? Are they all sperated by a space? Do the file names themselves have spaces in them? Did you make any changes to the code? Are you a comma delimeter, a space?

Comment: sorry i got it to work. @abraham, i really appreciate it!!!!!!